# how to limit the crawling depth in stormcrawler

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

my use-case is to extract text from website's any page and from the outlinks(that are present on that page only) only on daily basis. e.g. i want to crawl  all the links of (https://www.indiatimes.com/news/world) present on this page. this gives me few fresh news articles everyday. there are around 30-40 news articles links on this page everyday that i want to crawl and store in my database.

these are some configuration that i have for now -

here is the part of crawler-conf.yaml -

```
  parser.emitOutlinks: true
  perser.emitOutlinks.max.per.page: 0
  track.anchors: true
  metadata.track.path: true
  metadata.track.depth: true
```

here is the part of urlfilters.json-

```
 {
         "class":  "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.filtering.depth.MaxDepthFilter",
          "name": "MaxDepthFilter",
           "params": {
             "maxDepth": 0
                   }
 }
```

on these configurations this e.g. page is giving more than 35000 hits. it crawls the whole website that i dont need. it is getting more and more urls from outlinks. 
if i change  maxdepth parameter to 1 or 0 or 2, behaviour of crawl remains same.
is maxdepth parameter is right for this use case ?
i want to limit this recursive nature of crawl to only the  seed URL and outlinks of seed url. 
what does maxdepth parameter actually mean ?
what should i do to limit the crawl's expansion.

i am using stromcrawler 1.16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is exactly what the max depth filter is for. remember you need to rebuild your JAR with *mvn clean package* for any changes to the urlfilters.json to take effect.

if you don't want any outlinks when parsing a page, simply set *parser.emitOutlinks* to false in the config.